# Optimise Write performance on a RAID array of SSD

Tags: raid, ssd

We've 8 Samsung 970 Pro 1Tb drives (PCI3) in a HighPoint NVMe RAID Controller, which I want to optimise for write performance at the cost of any other consideration. All of our files will be around 10Mb, give or take a few percent. Currently this is set up with a blocksize on the raid of 512K (other options are 64K, 128K,256K) and a sector size of 512b, with options of (1K,2K and 4K). I know things get a bit odd with SSDs, as with spinning disks I would change the sector size to 4K.

The machine has a Threadripper with a very new motherboard and about 256Gb Ram running windows, so the hard drive infrastructure is likely to be the limiting factor.

Can anyone tell me anything that would improve this setup?

Thanks

Comment: both told devices are consumer grade hardware, what is the business related question and issue in here? since you not tell what kind of raid level is used (a secret?) what shall we suggest? Opinion based questions are offtopic

Comment: Sorry, they're all RAID0

Comment: Also what non-consumer hardware do you think would reach those write speeds. Aiming for about 25Gb/s

Comment: The theoretical maximum is 15Gb/s, limited by PCIe lanes of HighPoint card. The real perfromance will be lower.

Comment: [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning) can be a point, that this question might currently not on topic, moreover product suggestions also not. I would get in contact with a vendor to ask him if there is a server available that can handle 25gib/s, where at least more as a 100gbit link would require to suffer it